# Command history in emacs shell mode

Tags: bash, emacs

In the bash shell, I can use the up arrow key to navigate to a previously entered command. But this does not work in emacs shell mode. Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: Check out M-r too to look up a previous command quickly by searching.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`M-p` (and `M-n` for the other direction) will do the trick.

Here is the [link to the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Ring.html#Shell-Ring) on the subject.

Comment: In particular, I find `C-c C-l` very handy.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'comint-next-input)
```

Comment: It gives me "Symbol's value as variable is void: comint-mode-map" error

Comment: Maybe you need to do a `(require 'comint)` before? I don't have emacs installed right now, can't confirm the name of the library,

Comment: aha, that does it. Why didn't it occur to me? I feel stupid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Upvote.
I used ctrl+up and ctrl+down to navigate into shell/gdb history before. Not anymore thanks to your answer. thx.

Answer (score 1):

`C-p` and `C-n` and `C-r` work in (vanilla) bash too, along with some other emacs keys.  Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu Emacs, the menu for the Shell mode is called "In/Out".  (I think it also covers the more general mode called "comint".)